# Cisco 887va Port Forward

Tags: cisco, router, port-forwarding

Just trying to do some Port Forwarding on a Cisco 887VA and its proving to be a pain. I'm trying to port forward a few things like 8080 to the internet interface

First just let me start of by saying I've been looking around this place and a bunch of other support forums just for some reason no matter what solution I've been given it just does not seem to work for me. I've found a few questions on here and a few on the Cisco support forums.

The most annoying bit is that I'm almost 100% sure its the most simplistic of things.

So here's how it goes. I have a Cisco 887VA doing my VDSL connection routing to just one VLAN. It also does DHCP but that's just about it. My current topology just has one Host connected directly to the onboard switchports.

Here's the config; I hope someone can help :)

FYI: It has C880 V15.1(4)M4 Universal-K9

```
!
! No configuration change since last restart
version 15.1
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname VDSL
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable password 7 ***********
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 10
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-949938359
enrollment selfsigned
subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-949938359
revocation-check none
rsakeypair TP-self-signed-949938359
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-949938359
certificate self-signed 01
**************
quit
ip source-route
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.255
!
ip dhcp pool dhcp1
import all
network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.1.1
dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
ip dhcp-server 192.168.1.1
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
username admin privilege 15 secret 4 *******************
!
!
!
!
controller VDSL 0
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0
no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0.10
encapsulation dot1Q 10
pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface ATM0
no ip address
shutdown
no atm ilmi-keepalive
!
interface FastEthernet0
description Internal Switching between various switches and AP's
no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet1
description Internal Switching between various switches and AP's
no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet2
description Internal Switching between various switches and AP's
no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet3
description Internal Switching between various switches and AP's
no ip address
!
interface Vlan1
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
ip tcp adjust-mss 1380
!
interface Dialer1
ip address negotiated
ip access-group 103 in
ip mtu 1492
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly in
encapsulation ppp
dialer pool 1
dialer-group 1
ppp authentication chap pap callin
ppp chap hostname user@spark.co.nz
ppp chap password 7 *************
ppp pap sent-username user@xtrabb.co.nz password 7 140713181F13253920
hold-queue 224 in
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 102 interface Dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.2 8080 interface Dialer1 8080
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
!
access-list 102 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
password 7 **********************
login
transport input all
!
end
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you actually told us what you need help with :)

Comment: Silly me hahah, am just trying to do some port forwarding

Comment: If you mean that the forwarding of port 8080 is not working, what happens when you try to connect to that port on your public ip address from the outside? And is there anything in the router's syslog?

Comment: @hertitu I'll enable Information logging and post results

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the host on the network I was trying to port forward had lost its IP address and Gateway.

The nat appears to be working fine. Sorry for being a pain.

Thanks again,
Tactical.